# Атрибут is в HTML

Tags: html, html5

Недавно читал статьи по созданию собственных тегов в HTML и натолкнулся на неизвестный мне атрибут `is`. Статья: [https://learn.javascript.ru/...](https://learn.javascript.ru/webcomponent-core#%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Зачем этот атрибут? Можно ли его использовать, к примеру, для вставки иконок (`<i is="icon">..</i>`)? Насколько он валиден в старых браузерах?

Comment: [What is HTML “is” attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615661/2881286) и [спецификация](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#attr-is)

Comment: @Grundy, ну а для вставки иконки я могу его использовать? То, что этот атрибут означает новый элемент, с помощью которого указываются новый свойства, я понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is` является частью W3C спецификации и используется для создания пользовательских элементов HTML с пользовательским поведением.

В частности, `is` используется при расширении свойств встроенного элемента, например `<input>`, `<button>` или `<table>`. Например, вы можете установить `plastic-button` элемент для `<button>`, чтобы обеспечить некоторую причудливую анимацию при нажатии на кнопку.

Добавить эту кнопку можно следующим образом:

```
<button is="plastic-button">Click Me!</button>
```

Прежде чем вы это сделаете, вам необходимо зарегистрировать plastic-button, как пользовательский элемент HTML, например:

```js
customElements.define("plastic-button", PlasticButton, { extends: "button" });
```

Это ссылается на JavaScript класс `PlasticButton`, который выглядит примерно так:

```js
class PlasticButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Нарисуем некоторые причудливые анимационные эффекты!
    });
  }
}
```

Было бы здорово, если бы вы могли написать `<plastic-button>Click Me!</plastic-button>` вместо этого `<button is="plastic-button">Click Me!</button>`, но это создало бы HTMLElement без особого поведения.

Если вы НЕ хотите расширить свойства встроенного элемента HTML `<button>`, а вместо этого создаете новый элемент, который расширяет общий HTMLElement, вы можете использовать `<plastic-button>` синтаксис. Но вы не получите никакого `<button>` поведения.

Это часть спецификации W3C для пользовательских элементов веб-компонентов: http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#type-extension-semantics

<sub>перевод ответа [@DeanMoses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615661/2881286)</sub>

Comment: при переводе стоит указывать источник перевода.